# How to launch terminator from the terminal and then close the terminal without closing terminator

Tags: 20.04, gnome-terminal

I'm using **Ubuntu 20.04** and I want to run the [GNOME terminator](https://github.com/gnome-terminator/terminator) from the terminal in a specific folder path and then close the terminal, can you tell me how can I do that please? thanks in advance.

> Note: I don't want to make terminator my default bash terminal.

Comment: I know there is an answer here about it, but all you should have to do is first run `terminator &` from any directory then in the same old terminal run `disown`.

Comment: @Terrance thanks, I confirm that `terminator &` solved my problem, and `disown` solve this issue completely without the `&`.